# Why does the verb πολυπραγμονεῖν use the noun stem and not the verb stem? (Greek)

Tags: greek, verbs, plato, compound-verb

In Plato's *Republic*, Socrates sets forth the following idea, which he later refutes:

> τὸ τὰ αὑτοῦ πράττειν καὶ μὴ πολυπραγμονεῖν δικαιοσύνη ἐστί,
>
> justice is to do one's own business and not to do too much,

([4.433a](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0167%3Abook%3D4%3Asection%3D433a))

What's odd, grammatically speaking, is that the compound verb πολυπραγμονεῖν ("to do a lot") doesn't use the verb stem πράττειν, which appears earlier in the clause.

Why does the compound verb πολυπραγμονεῖν use the noun stem instead of the verb stem? Is this common? I would expect to see πολυπράττειν instead.

Comment: In this context it actually means "to poke around in s.o. elseʼs business" (Montanari).

Comment: [πολυπραγμονέω](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=polupragmone%2Fw&la=greek&can=polupragmone%2Fw0&prior=polupra/gmatos).  I found [πραγματεύομαι](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=pragmateu%2Fomai&la=greek&can=pragmateu%2Fomai0&prior=pragma/teuma).  πράττω/[πράσσω](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dpra%2Fttw) seems to have the opposite meaning.  Not doing to much ("passing over") vs. doing the many things involved in ones own business.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The verb doesn't actually mean simply 'to do many things' – though that idea could conceivably be rendered by πολυπράττειν, if such a verb existed (it isn't attested in LSJ), or by πολλὰ πράττειν. Instead, it's a denominative verb (a verb formed from the stem of a substantive or adjective). In this case, it's formed from the adjective πολυπράγμων, 'meddlesome,' 'officious,' 'a busybody,' and therefore means something like 'to be a busybody.' (In fact, the LSJ entry for πολυπραγμονέω cites this passage from the *Republic* as an example of the meaning 'to be a meddlesome, inquisitive busybody.')

The section of Smyth's Greek grammar about denominative verbs (§866-868) lists -εω is one of the principle terminations for denominative verbs (§866.2):

> **-εω:** derived chiefly from ο/ε-stems (384 f), and thence extended to all kinds of stems. Verbs in -εω denote a *condition* or an *activity*, and are often intransitive.

The example in Smyth that offers the closest parallel with πολυπραγμονέω (< πολυπράγμων) is σωφρονέω, 'to be temperate' (< σώφρων).

Comment: Good answer. What would make it even better is a description of the suffix *-μων*...